# sequences and bounds proof

Tags: analysis

I am solving the following problem:

> Let $S \subset R$ be a nonempty subset which is bounded above. Let $z=\sup{S}$. Prove that there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n \in S$ for all $n$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n}=z.$

I know $z-\epsilon<z$, and if I can find a an inside then I will have found the Sup. What I mean by that is that we can find an element in $S$ that lies inside this epsilon interval.

From here I'm kind of lost. I would appreciate some help. Please and thank you.

Comment: Stop posting the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N},\ $ the interval $\left(z-\frac{1}{n},\ z\right]\ $ contains a member of $S,\ $ for otherwise $z$ would not be the supremum of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}>0$ $\forall n$ in natural numbers, assings that $n$ to diferent $a_{n}$ elements on $S$ using the $\epsilon$ definition of supreme. Then the fact that {$\dfrac{1}{k}$} $\longmapsto 0$.